# Navigation bar work fine on Ios 8 is not shown on Ios 7.1

Tags: xcode, ios8, storyboard, xcode6, ios7.1

i'm creating an App with the latest xcode 6 and Ios 8 SDK.

I have this simple ViewController where i set a Navigation item from storyboard with a title and a right button as you can see on the image:

[image]

This ViewController is pushed by an HomeViewController.

I used Auto Layout.

Now what happen is that on Ios 8 all is working fine and when from the home i click on a button, the view controller is pushed in a right way as you can see in the image:

[image]

But when i do the same action on Ios 7.1 i see only this:

[image]

The navigation is not showing, no title, no button.

I made the connection from HomeViewController and the "Step1ViewController" from storyboad.
I'm loosing something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Andrew my problem was that in the viewDidLoad i forgot to call
[super viewDidLoad];
This don't create problem in iOs8 but yes on iOs7.
Maybe you have forgot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Giuseppe suggested, you may forgot to add

```
super.viewDidLoad()
```

or objc

```
[super viewDidLoad];
```

in the viewDidLoad method. This worked for me.